# Software / API to simulate OBD II and gps data

Tags: gps, simulator, obd-ii

I am currently developing a solution for bus-tracking.

Among other things, the implementation of properly configured routers is taking a long time.
So in the sake of testing, I made a quick node-red flow that simulates the GPS positioning on a bus route.

Are there any tools/software/API available for free that simulate the message sent by a car that includes OBD II data as well as GPS coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with [Freematics OBD Emulator](https://freematics.com/pages/products/freematics-obd-emulator-mk2/) which only simulate the OBD 2 data (and there are many problems with it if you are a pro-user!).
But GPS and OBD data together as an API I could not find any.

The link I mentioned would be a good start for googling. Maybe you are lucky. Please make a comment here and share it if you find any as well.